# How to use argparse without needing to define arguments?

Tags: python, argparse

Using the very interesting answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27529806/14864907), I would like to be able to use argparse and **execute multiple functions without having to define the arguments to each function**. Otherwise the code is very overloaded or one has to multiply files to run different functions, which is not very practical either.

In the following example, the functions `function1` and `function2` have different arguments such as: `function1(arg1: int, arg2: bool)` and `function2(arg3: float, arg4: str)`

```py
# file test.py
import argparse
from file1 import function1
from file2 import function2

FUNCTION_MAP = {'function1' : function1, 'function2': function2}

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('command', choices=FUNCTION_MAP.keys())

# no specific argument to add here. 

args = parser.parse_args()


func = FUNCTION_MAP[args.command]
func(**vars(args))
```

The following commands with `--` arguments do not work.

`python test.py "function1" --arg1=10 --arg2=True`

`python test.py "function2" --arg3=2.4 --arg4="a_file.csv"`

command as `python test.py "function1"` works but asks me the arguments of the `function1`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should use [subparsers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59087911/3279716), in the `run_command` function instead of printing you can get and call the correct function instead of using an `if/else`

Comment: How are you planning to get the values from the command line? I think you are overcomplicating your design here. At the moment you're heading towards using [`parser.parse_known_args()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args) to get the command and then re-parse the unspecified flags in your functions. Either way, you're going to have to specify your arguments and flags at some point.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions (I edited the code). Knowing the arguments of the functions it's me ideally who defines the values in the command line. For example I could put `python test.py "function2" --arg3=3 --arg4='a.csv'` **without the need to put constraints on the arguments** with `parser.add_argument`.

Comment: The primary purpose of `argparse` is to parse arguments, not to execute commands.  Its help and error checking are of little use if you don't define arguments.  If you don't want those, parse the `sys.argv` list directly. (and save yourself the work of understanding `argparse`)

Comment: Who's `me`?  The writer of the script, or the end user who calls the script?  `argparse` gives the writer control, with usage guides and error checking.  It's  not intended for free form commandline input.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you very much, yes I had already looked into `sys.argv` but argparse seemed to be a much more elegant solution, ideally `me` is the user intended to call the script. I could for example give it the following directly python `test.py "function2" --arg3=${float} --arg4=${csv file}`. The idea of the script in my question is to allow the user to directly execute a large number of methods with the arguments he wants and without having dozens of extra lines of code by defining the `parser.add_argument` for each function. I guess it's theoretically possible though?

Comment: All you are using `argparse` for is to grab `sys.argv[1]`.  It does not provide any tools for converting `--arg3=${float}`

Comment: @hpaulj no sorry my bad, I have updated now with specific examples so that you can have a better idea.

Comment: In principle it's possible to create parsers on the fly that match a function signature but this would be quite precarious and would lead to a fair amount of code for handling edge cases. For example passing `--arg2=False` would result in `True` when parsing the string `False` with `bool`

Comment: There are third party parsers like https://pypi.org/project/plac/ that can create a parser that is customized for a set of functions like yours.  It uses annotations to determine what kind of arguments your function(s) require, and defines `argparse` like arguments accordingly.  There may be other packages like that, but `plac` is one that I used years ago.

Comment: @hpaulj sounds great, `plac` handles arguments without defining them but I didn't see in the doc if you can choose the function to call? I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/ialbert/plac/issues/60).

Answer (score 0):

If functions will be shuttling around/sharing lots of the same data, sounds like you want a class/object?

`myobj.fn1()` and `myobj.fn2()` will both have implicit access to the `myobj` object's data.

Use argparse input to define the initial instance via your class' `__init__(self, x, y ...)` method.

Comment: The two functions have **strictly** different arguments. So it would be awkward to share the same builder (__init__), right?

Comment: If the data is related, they could totally live in the same object, even if each fn only transacts on a subset. Or extend the idea to have 2 parallel classes if the data isn't related.