# Python: different argparse for multiple classes launched from the same file

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I'm developing an environment for experiments. Each experiment is a separate class has a different arguments required. The concept is to have a set of arguments that are related to the whole experimenting environment and a set of arguments imported from an experiment class. The question is: how to update possible arguments accordingly to chosen experiment type.

How i would love to make it basically looks like:

Note: `EXPERIMENTS` is a dict with experiment classes mapped by their names

**main.py**

```py
def main(args):
    experiment()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument("experiment_name",
                        metavar='experiment_name',
                        type=str,
                        choices=EXPERIMENTS.keys(), #exported list of available experiments
                        help="Choose an experiment to run. Available: "+str(list(EXPERIMENTS.keys())),
                        )
    args = parser.parse_args()
    EXPERIMENTS[args.experiment_name].add_args(parser)

    experiment = EXPERIMENTS[args.experiment_name]()

    sys.exit(main(args) or 0)
```

**experimentA.py**

```py
class ExperimentA(Experiment):
    
    @classmethod
    def add_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--expA-arg')
        cls.args = parser.parse_args()
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.args = self.__class__.args
        self.param = self.args.expA_arg

    def __call__(self):
        run_the_experiment_A()
```

**experimentB.py**

```py
class ExperimentB(Experiment):
    
    @classmethod
    def add_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--expB-arg')
        cls.args = parser.parse_args()
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.args = self.__class__.args
        self.param = self.args.expB_arg

    def __call__(self):
        run_the_experiment_B()
```

And how to achieve it to see those results after calling from shell:

**case 1**

IN:

`python3 main.py -h`

OUT:

```
positional arguments:
  experiment_name  Choose an experiment to run. Available: ['ExperimentA', 'ExperimentB']

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
```

**case 2**

IN:

`python3 main.py ExperimentA -h`

OUT:

```
positional arguments:
  experiment_name  Choose an experiment to run. Available: ['ExperimentA', 'ExperimentB']

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  --expA-arg
```

**case 3**

IN:

`python3 main.py ExperimentB -h`

OUT:

```
positional arguments:
  experiment_name  Choose an experiment to run. Available: ['ExperimentA', 'ExperimentB']

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  --expB-arg
```

Comment: Instead of using a positional argument you should use [`argparse subparsers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59087911/3279716), you can associate the parsers with each class and just return the subparser for each one.

Comment: Thank you. It solved the issue. Now it works perfectly as expected :)

Comment: You should post your solution here so that others can see how it was resolved.